# DAX running total + starting value

Tags: dax, powerpivot, cumulative-sum

I am fairly new to the DAX universe, but scrolling around I managed to successfully implement a cumulative (running) total, with a measure defined along this structure:   `Running_Total_QTY:=CALCULATE(SUM(Reporting[QTY]),FILTER(ALL(Reporting[DATE_R]),Reporting[DATE_R]<=MAX(Reporting[DATE_R])))`

For a table that looks like this:

```
ID  DATE_R          QTY
A1  5/11/2018 9:00  5
A1  5/11/2018 9:01  10
A1  5/11/2018 9:01  -5
A1  5/11/2018 9:02  50
A1  5/11/2018 9:05  -20
B1  5/11/2018 9:00  3
B1  5/11/2018 9:01  -20
B1  5/11/2018 9:01  4
B1  5/11/2018 9:02  20
B1  5/11/2018 9:03  10
```

The problem is that I would need to add to this running total a starting QTY - *QTY_INIT*, which I receive from another table that looks like this:

```
ID1 QTY_INIT
A1  100
B1  200
```

By trial and error I have succeeded by creating a second measure that calculates the average (of 1 item!) defined like this:

```
Average_starting_quantity:=CALCULATE(AVERAGE(Starting_Quantity[QTY_INIT]),FILTER(ALL(Starting_Quantity[ID1]),Starting_Quantity[ID1]=LASTNONBLANK(Reporting[ID],TRUE())))
```

And then just adding the two measures together.

```
Running_plus_total:=[Running_Total_QTY]+[Average_starting_quantity]
```

This method works, but is very inefficient and very slow (the data set is quite big).

How can I add QTY_INIT from the second table directly without using a "fake" average (or max, min, etc..)? How can I optimize the measure for a faster performance?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Regards

Comment: Is there any business reason stopping you from appending the initial values to the start of your data set?  Since then you would have all the data in one table, which would mean that you would get your result with just your [Running_Total_QTY] measure.

Comment: Hi Marcus, thanks. In principle that is the most elegant solution, but I would prefer to avoid appending the data, because I have many more analyzes that need the initial quantity to be left out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this instead of your `Average_starting_quantity`?

```
StartingQty = LOOKUPVALUE(Starting_Quantity[QTY_INIT],
                          Starting_Quantity[ID1], MAX(Reporting[ID]))
```

---

If your tables are related on `ID` and `ID1` with cross filter direction going both ways,

[image]

then you can just use

```
StartingQty = MAX(Starting_Quantity[QTY_INIT])
```

since the filter context on `ID` will flow through to `ID1`.

Comment: Thanks!
Your first approach works for me, but I had to substitute MAX with LASTNONBLANK because Reporting[ID] is a string returned an error.(I'm running on Excel not Power BI - in case that makes a difference).

The second approach also worked with a tweak.In Excel it seems that I can't explicitly define the crossfilter to be bi-directional, but looking at this link [link](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/many-to-many-relationships-in-power-bi-and-excel-2016/)  I modified your suggestion to work:
`CALCULATE(MAX(Starting_Quantity[ID1]), CROSSFILTER(Reporting[ID],Starting_Quantity[ID1],Both))`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out those differences. I work more with Power BI, which does indeed work slightly differently.